# Android - How to implement SSL Pinning with Volley similar to Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to implement ssl pinning in Volley. In retrofit its very simple by OkHttpClient.Builder and adding CertificatePinner in it.

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("release")) {
          builder.certificatePinner(getCertificatePinner());
    }

public static CertificatePinner getCertificatePinner() {
        CertificatePinner pinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                .add(BuildConfig.DOMAIN_XYZ, "sha256/bdRp8e7SKBCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")
                .build();
        return pinner;
    }
```

Any similar simple way to implement SSL Pinning in Volley?

Comment: Android Volley is a very lightweight library. As far as I know it doe snot support pinning at all, therefore the only way would be to use pinning via `network_security_config.xml` https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CertificatePinning

Comment: @Robert if we use network_security_config.xml approach then before the expiry of the certificate we will have to update the app manually and the old users using previous app versions will get impacted.

Comment: Usually you don't pin the certificate but the public key. Even if the certificate is refreshed the public key stays the same. Only if a key is compromised the key is also changed.